# Where can I find Morningstar after fully claiming their Territory?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

After I get 100% in all Morningstar territory, will I still be able to find Morningstar there?

Answer (score 2):

You will not.

However, if you replay city takeover missions in their former territory, Morningstar members will show up within the mission.

Comment: Also, you can cancel the mission; if there are any Morningstar members present, they'll still be there. Your Gang Wanted meter will be reset, but if you shoot the Morningstar guys right in front of you, you'll pick up Gang Wanted again for Morningstar, and they'll send people after you. (One star isn't enough; you'll want two or three, so make sure to have around 2 cars worth of gang members visible when you cancel the mission.)

Answer (score 1):

You can encounter Morningstar gang members through a [Survival](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Survival) diversion.

From Saints Row Wiki's "[Survival](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Survival)" article:

> There are 26 Survivals in total. 24 Survivals are available as soon as
>   the mission [We're Going to Need Guns](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/We%27re_Going_to_Need_Guns) is completed. One more unlocks
>   after the mission [Party Time](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Party_Time) and the final one can be completed after
>   the mission [Zombie Attack](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Zombie_Attack).
>
> How the game chooses to offer Survivals to the player depends on
>   whether all storyline missions are completed or not.
>
> - If not all the storyline missions are completed, no successfully completed Survival will be offered to the player again. This means for
>     example that before completion of [Party Time](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Party_Time), Survival Calls will stop
>     if the available 24 are done.
> - If all storyline missions are complete then all 26 Survival Calls repeat randomly. This means that any Survival is as likely to be
>     offered as any other, no matter its completion status.

According to the Saints Row Wiki, [there are 7 Survival diversion calls where you will encounter Morningstar gang members out of the 26 Survival diversion calls.](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Survival#Calls)

### Mods

You can get more frequent calls offering Survival missions with the **[Realism mod](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/realism-mod.731/)**. Related changelog: "*Calls from survival missions are now more frequently*". Note that if you only want Realism mod's Survival diversion changes and not its other changes, you only need to install its `sr3_city_survival.xtbl` file ([you'll need to extract it first](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/saints-row-the-third-modding-basics.597/) or [download it here](http://www.mediafire.com/?ddu8u16rs1oo9r6)), and none of its other files. Put `sr3_city_survival.xtbl` in the SR3 root directory.

With the [**Random Encounters Mod**](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/random-encounters-mod.2784/)...

> ... you will find yourself attacked by either Morningstar, Luchadores or Deckers during freeroam in some certain interval of time.

This mod will allow you to encounter Morningstar gang members even after you took over all of their territory.

Another mod solution is to use the **[Mission Replay](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/mission-replay-v8.158/)** mod. Like its name suggests, it allows you to replay already finished missions. With that mod, you can choose to replay a [mission](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Missions_in_Saints_Row:_The_Third) where you encounter Morningstar gang members.

Note that Random Encounters and Mission Replay's `sr3city.lua` files are not compatible with each other. You will need to overwrite their files with a [merged `sr3city.lua` file](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/random-encounters-mod.2784/page-2#post-43650) (which you can get [here](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/random-encounters-mod.2784/page-2#post-43650)) if you want to use those two mods together.

Answer (score 0):

No, apparently they will not appear once you own 100% of their gang operations.

**Taunt Achievement**

If you want to get the achievement by taunting gang members you should either go to co-op, start a new game, or taunt your own game members. A lot of people overlook this achievement and they end up having to do a trick in order to beat it when it could have been a lot easier before the 100%.

Sources

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/954855-/61451574

http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=345086